# How many applications can a single, optimized SSH-only Raspberry Pi B handle?

Tags: raspbian, performance, server

How many "passive, common, server-like tasks" can a *single* home-used RPi perform in parallel? There are many things you can have a RPi serving, like a NAS, a webserver (PHP+SQL), a git repository, a media server, a WLAN access point, ...

But how many of them can a single home-used Raspberry Pi B serve in parallel? Assuming: up-to-date Raspbian and firmware with SSH-only access (GUI disabled fully) and optimized settings like cleaned off of unneeded packages, overclocked, only 16 MB VRAM, fast SD card and so on.

I know this heavily depends on the actual usage and the concrete setup, but are there some general statements that always hold?

What server applications *definitely* need their own RPi and would suffer if other tasks would run on the same RPi?

What tasks are there that use almost no power and can run parallel on the same RPi?

Example use case:

- Network server: WLAN access point, webserver (PHP+SQL), git repository for one or two handful of people

Comment: having multiple server services running, the performance heavily depends on how many users use them and how they use it. in general, all you mentioned is running fine simultaneously on the pi. maybe you can name some usage examples

Comment: @Gotschi Thanks. In my case it would mainly be a webserver, a WLAN access point and a git repository for a handful of people at maximum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git repo and the LAMP server might run smoothly for ~five concurrent users (also depends on your project's files - big/small/how many... and your websites performance in general)

- maybe try different http servers (lighttpd etc..)
- a wordpress 3.9 with 10 pages and ~10 plugins takes about two seconds to load for me (try various caching plugins, maybe not in dev mode ;))

You can get in performance trouble with the wifi access point, depends on what your clients transfer. Maybe start without encyrption and then try and see what happens when you use WEP or even WPA...

I'd suggest using a fast SD card with only the base system on it and a usb stick/hdd with your hosted files, maybe even boot from a fast usb stick. And if you overclock: make yourself a backup from time to time! Corruption can and will happen, even when not overclocked!